# Android - close Main Activity with back button ~ errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, back

First, sorry for my **low programming skills**.
I'm trying to write my *first Java application* for Android (actually I *never* studied Java but I get along with that most of all).

Anyway, I'm trying to make this app closing on Back button press. This is the code, with errors [1][2][3].

```
    @Override
[1]    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
       {
[2]        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
       {
[3]            finish();
       }
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }


/**
     * [1]KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a type
     * [2]KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a variable
     * [3]Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type 
          Activity
 */
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: how come "return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);" is outside the bracket ?

Comment: You're probably missing imports for KeyEvent. Also, don't call finish() from a static method.

Comment: In the code it's not outside the bracket, I only  forgot to crop it. Sorry :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import KeyEvent package which is `android.view.KeyEvent`... `import android.view.KeyEvent;`

Everytime you use a class which comes from a different package of java (`java.lang` is the default) you should add `import` to say to the compiler where it should take the class. Eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA/Netbeans help you to import packages by using a simple key combination so use one of them if you can.

For error 3: Your return is out of the method body!

[What is a package?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

If you want to learn more about android dev, read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it).

Comment: I forgot to crop the } , sorry.

Comment: Try to add the missing imports, maybe your error 3 is caused by this

Comment: fixed [2] thanks to @Marco . there's still at [1]The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) of type MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment must override or implement a supertype method;
at [3] same error and at line 4 new error: The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type Fragment

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, it can organize all your imports for you. If you are on a PC use Ctrl + Shift + O, on a mac Command + shift + o. That will help you out with all your import stuff

Comment: 0 imports added ...
(very useful, though! - didn't know there was that shortcut, thank you anyway)

Comment: Because you already added all missed imports! Your problem is a bit more complex, i mean try error says your class don't have a onKeyDown to override.. You should add more code.

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: Yes, open a new question and add more code. Because with the current code we can't help you

Comment: opened Android - close Main Activity with back button ~ errors II

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an activity, try overriding the method obBackPressed

> **public void onBackPressed ()**
>
> Added in API level 5 Called when the activity has detected the user's
>   press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the
>   current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){
   // Do some stuff
   finish();
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

That would save you some trouble.